# Can I execute `START_QUERY` and `CONTINUE_QUERY` discontinuously?

Tags: rethinkdb

With the same connection I want to execute `query` sequence as below.

1. Start `GET_ALL`
2. Some other query
3. Continue `GET_ALL`
4. Some other query
5. ...

Is this pattern supported by rethinkdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, but it is not recommended.

Step 3 will wait for step 2 to finish.

Comment: That was what I am expecting